# the difference between "chance upon" and "came across"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I cannot figure out how should I recognize usage of these phrasal verbs.

Can I use them interchangeably? For example as in the sentence:

> "I *chanced upon */* came across* a new way of exercising."

Comment: Note that _chance upon_ is present tense and _came across_ is past.

Comment: Also note that "literary" ***chance upon*** is [very uncommon compared to "everyday" ***come across***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+chanced+upon+a%2CI+came+across+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Do you want to sound like a Victorian poet, or a modern speaker of English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both phrases can be used interchangeably. Both phrases mean to discover or encounter something unexpectedly or by chance.

These are the definitions from [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/):

> **[chance upon](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chance-on?q=chance%20upon)**: to find or see someone or something when you did not expect to
> *Example*: I was browsing in a bookshop when I chanced upon an old friend.

> **[come across](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-across)**: to meet someone, or to find something by chance
> *Example*: I came across a word I’d never seen before.

Also, **chance on** can be used like **chance upon** as well. They have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is very much the same but I'm not sure if they both belong in the same range of styles. "Come across" I'd happily say in a casual conversation. "Chance upon" feels like something I'd expect to read in a book instead.